# Hide console window in Windows Forms application

Tags: c++, console, winforms

I took over a Visual C++ project in Visual Studio 2005 from a colleague. It is a Windows Forms project (I assume). But when I start it, besides the Windows Form it also shows a console window. How do I get rid of this console window? I think it must be a project setting but I don't find it.

Any help is appreciated ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the project properties for all configurations (Project | Properties, choose Configuration 'All Configurations', locate Config Properties -> Linker -> System), change the SubSystem from Console to Windows.